# How to find string like in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, screen-scraping

how can i scrape if i know only half of the title of sibling in bs4?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from urllib import request
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
html = request.urlopen(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Ehresmann)
bs = BS(html.read(), 'html.parser')
    
data = pd.DataFrame({''known for':[],)}
    try:
        name = bs.find('h1').text
    except:
        name = ''
    try:
        known = bs.find('th',string = 'Known.*').next_element.text #?
    except:
        known = ''
```

Thanks for ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :contains and next_sibling

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Ehresmann')
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('th:contains("Known")').next_sibling.get_text('\n').split('\n'))
```

Not as a list:

```
print(soup.select_one('th:contains("Known")').next_sibling.get_text('\n'))
```